# How to remove URL from WooCommerce My account order number

Tags: php, wordpress, list, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove the URL from the WooCommerce My account Orders page and I really don't know how to do it by editing functions.php. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

[order details url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UeCm.png)

I tried some of the answers I found on StackOverflow but I doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the existing order-number column using the first hook as it prints the order number along with the link.
Add a custom order order-number column to print as per your requirement using the second hook

```
function remove_defualt_order_number_column($columns) {

    unset($columns['order-number']);
    $custom_order_number = array('order-number-custom' => __('Order', 'woocommerce'));
    $columns = array_merge($custom_order_number, $columns);
    return $columns;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'remove_defualt_order_number_column', 10, 1);



add_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-number-custom', 'add_custom_order_number_column', 10, 1);

function add_custom_order_number_column($order) {
    echo esc_html(_x('#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce') . $order->get_order_number());
}
```